# Why are my labels stacking on top of each other inside my QHBoxLayout?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmainwindow, qlayout

Simply enough, I want to add two labels inside an horizontal box layout using Python's PYQT5.

When I execute this code, the two labels appear on top of each other, even though adding them to a QHBoxLayout should position them from left to right.

How can I fix this?

- Compiler : Python 3.7.4 32 bit
- IDE : Visual Studio Code
- OS : Windows 10

my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Interface(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = 'debug'
        self.mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.initGUI()

    def initGUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(0,0,200,200)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)

        label1 = QLabel('test 1',self)
        label2 = QLabel('test 2',self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(label1)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(label2)

        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.show()    

    def close_application(self):
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Interface()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Explanation:

QMainWindow is a special widget that has a default layout:

[image]

that does not allow to establish another layout and clearly indicates the error message that is obtained when executing your code in the terminal/CMD:

```
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on Interface "", which already has a layout
```

So when the layout is not established, it does not handle the position of the QLabels, and you, when passing as a parent to window-`self`, both will be set in the window in the top-left position.

#### Solution:

As [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#creating-main-window-components) points out, you must create a central widget that is used as a container and then set the layout:

```
def initGUI(self):
    self.setGeometry(0,0,200,200)
    self.setFixedSize(self.size())
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)

    central_widget = QWidget() # <---
    self.setCentralWidget(central_widget) # <---

    label1 = QLabel('test 1')
    label2 = QLabel('test 2')
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(label1)
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(label2)

    central_widget.setLayout(self.mainLayout) # <---
    self.show()
```